# How to access existing Amazon DynamoDB Table?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

**General Problem**

I have followed [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html) on creating and accessing an Amazon DynamoDB from an Android application, and then adapted it for use in an app I am writing. It works great despite the difficulties I faced getting it up and running. However, I would also like to be able to access the database using a python script running on my Raspberry Pi.

I have found [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.html), but it seems to only describe how to interact with a local DynamoDB table.

**Specific Problem**

The following code connects and writes an item to a DynamoDB table. I can't find any sort of endpoint URL for my Amazon DynamoDB, only the ARN, and there is no passing of a password or username as I use in my App.

```
# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)    

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")    

table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')    

title = "The Big New Movie"
year = 2015    

response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'year': year,
        'title': title,
        'info': {
            'plot':"Nothing happens at all.",
            'rating': decimal.Decimal(0)
        }
    }
)
```

I have searched for any sort of instructions for connecting to an Amazon DynamoDB instance, but everything I have found describes a local table. If anyone can give advice for the specific issue or recommend a tutorial to that effect, I would appreciate it immensely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")
```

To

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name='REGION')
```

Where REGION is the name of your dynamodb region, such as 'us-west-2'. It will then connect to AWS DynamoDB instance.

EDIT: If you haven't do so already, you will need to setup your [AWS Credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html). There are several options for this. One option is to use environment variables

> Boto3 will check these environment variables for credentials:
>
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID The access key for your AWS account.
>
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY The secret key for your AWS account.